# Pandas not properly installed in venv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip, virtualenv

On ubuntu 16.4.4 with Python `2.7.12`, I was trying to install `pandas` and some other packages with `pip` in `virtualenv`. The installation proceeded without any errors. However, when I try to import pandas, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: umpy.core.multiarray failed to import not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

My system has pandas of the same version(`0.18.0`) and runs without any problem.

What I tried and did not work:

- create a new virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` option.
- reinstall pandas (in venv)
- upgrade pandas (in venv)
- upgrade numpy (from 1.11.0 to 1.14.3) (in venv)
- uninstall numpy and pandas and install pandas again (in venv)

Comment: How about fresh env, without `--system-site-package`?

Comment: As mentioned, tried also, surprisingly did not work. I don't know if it is more a `pip`, `pandas` or `numpy` problem because even in such a virtualenv `pip` install of the list of packages lead to the same error.

Comment: Then I'd try `pip install numpy=1.11.0 pandas==0.18.0 --force-reinstall --upgrade` based on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a similar problem to this one https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18530 i.e. mismatch between some specific versions of numpy and pandas. The `pip install numpy --upgrade` didn't work for me but

`python -m pip install pandas==0.18.0 --force-reinstall --upgrade --no-deps --no-cache`

did the trick in my case (I encountered this problem on fresh Ubuntu 17.10, python2).

Comment: This should work too, just mind to specify the numpy version.

Comment: Wouldn't the `--no-deps` pprevent Pandas from installing numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Update `numpy` version:

`pip install numpy --upgrade`

Should fix the error.

Comment: Sorry, I did not finish editing the question before you answered. I tried upgrading both pandas and numpy but it did not work. Also it might be a problem in my work because the requirements for the project ask for numpy 1.11.0.